# perl how to assign the individual values out to variable

Tags: perl, perl-hash

I am trying to assign the hash values to variables, but I'm unable to get each value assigned to a varIAble. Please share your thoughts

```
say my %data = Dumper($data);   

$VAR1 = {
          'cnt' => 2000,
          'inc' => 30,
          'start' => 1440154820,
          'end' => 1440154860,
          'values' => [
                        '0.001234',
                        '0.001878',
                        '0.001849',
```

#### expected output

```
$start = 0.001234:1440154820
$end = 0.001849:1440154860
```

Hi, I am trying to get these values assigned to variables as below from the above hash

```
$value1 = 0.001234:1440154820   # like $VAR1{values[0]:$VAR1{start}
$value2 = 0.001849:1440154860   # $VAR1{values[2]:$VAR1{end}
```

Comment: You say you're trying to do this. But you haven't shown us any of the code you've tried. We can, of course, just give you the answer. But it's probably more useful if we see the mistakes that you've made and explain where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're asking for?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = {
  cnt    => 2000,
  inc    => 30,
  start  => 1440154820,
  end    => 1440154860,
  values => [0.001234, 0.001878, 0.001849],
};

my $start = join ':', $data->{values}[0], $data->{start};
my $end   = join ':', $data->{values}[2], $data->{end};

print "\$start = $start\n";
print "\$end   = $end\n";
```

#### output

```
$start = 0.001234:1440154820
$end   = 0.001849:1440154860
```